# pythonプログラム実行時にエラーも出さずにログインパネルに移動してしまう。

Tags: python, ios, 機械学習, pycharm, anaconda3

理系大学院生からの質問です。
プログラミングに慣れ親しんでいる同期や先輩に質問してもみんな答えられないので、詳しい方がいたら教えて頂きたいです。

・anaconda3で仮想環境を作り、pycharmを使ってpythonのプログラミングを行っています。(mac)
・先輩の書いたプログラムをpycharmで実行しようとすると、実行した途端何故かmacのログインパネル(電源を入れた時のユーザーを選択する画面)に移動してしまいます。
・エラーメッセージは出ません。
・Windowsだとうまくいくっぽいです。
・ほかのプログラムではうまく実行できます。

考えられるうる原因は何でしょうか？このような例がどこにも載っていなくて困っています。
プログラムの内容は、海外の大学が作成した分析ソフトを先輩がいじったもので、かなり複雑だと思います。

Comment: 最低限どのようなプログラムなのかを提示してもらわないと答えようが無い気がします。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、ぜひ追記してみてください。

Comment: 面白い症状だなあ、と思ってググってみたらそれっぽいのがありました: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14999